# Cannot convert UIKit.UIViewController iOS on Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to increase the code reuse and readability of my app by extracting some parameters into a helper class, `UIHelper.cs`.

The problem I have is that in trying to extract the method for setting the layout, I am getting these errors.
Still unable to resolve, if anybody could share to someone who might know that'd be great.

```
/Users/richardcurteis/Development/XamarinProjects/NoteTaker/iOS/UIHelper.cs(30,30): Error CS1502:
The best overloaded method match for `UIKit.UITableView.UITableView(Foundation.NSCoder)' has some invalid arguments (CS1502) (NoteTaker.iOS)
```

And

```
/Users/richardcurteis/Development/XamarinProjects/NoteTaker/iOS/UIHelper.cs(47,47): Error CS1503:
Argument `#1' cannot convert `UIKit.UIViewController' expression to type `Foundation.NSCoder' (CS1503) (NoteTaker.iOS)
```

I am passing the `this` back from the originating controller so the method has the correct reference. I thought the controller must be an object of `UIViewController`

As such I do not understand why this is the wrong type.
Thanks in advance.

`UIHelper.cs`

```
using System;
using UIKit;

namespace NoteTaker.iOS
{
    public class UIHelper : UIViewController
    {

        UIViewController controller;

        public UIHelper ()
        {

        }

        public UIColor SetNavBarRGB ()
        {
            UIColor uiColour = UIColor.FromRGB (255, 0, 255);
            return uiColour;
        }

        public UIStringAttributes NavBarForeGroundColour ()
        {
            UIStringAttributes navBarForeGroundColour = new UIStringAttributes () { ForegroundColor = UIColor.White };
            return navBarForeGroundColour;
        }

        public UITableView TableLayoutHelper (UIViewController controller)
        {

            UITableView tableLayout = new UITableView (controller) { // Error appears here
                Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (0, this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame.Bottom,
                    controller.View.Bounds.Width,
                    controller.View.Bounds.Height - controller.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame.Height),
            };
            return tableLayout;
        }
    }
}
```

`MainViewController.cs`

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using UIKit;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NoteTaker.iOS
{
    partial class MainViewController : UIViewController
    {
        List<Note> notes;
        UITableView table;
        UIHelper uiHelper;


        public MainViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
            notes = new List<Note> ();
            uiHelper = new UIHelper();
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()

        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = uiHelper.SetNavBarRGB();
            this.Title = "Notes";
            this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TitleTextAttributes = uiHelper.NavBarForeGroundColour ();

            table = uiHelper.TableLayoutHelper (this); // Method called here
            this.View.Add (table);

            var addButton = new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add);
            addButton.TintColor = UIColor.White;

            this.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItems = new UIBarButtonItem[] { addButton };
            addButton.Clicked += (sender, e) => {
                this.NavigationController.PushViewController (new NoteViewController(), true);
            };

            notes = Database.getNotes ();
            table.Source = new NotesTableViewSource (notes, this);
        }

        public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
            notes = Database.getNotes ();
            table.Source = new NotesTableViewSource(notes, this );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, user error as per usual. The code was fine and worked as intended. 
The problem lay in this method, I had one of the variables calling, `this` rather than the `controller` argument that was passed to the method.

```
public UITableView TableLayoutHelper (UIViewController controller)
        {

            UITableView tableLayout = new UITableView (controller) { // Error appears here
                Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (0, this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame.Bottom,
                    controller.View.Bounds.Width,
                    controller.View.Bounds.Height - controller.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame.Height),
            };
            return tableLayout;
        }
```

`this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame.Bottom`

Should have been,

`controller.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame.Bottom`

Corrected, the code now works fine